# SQL - Find minimum active date

Tags: sql

So I have three columns that are important. CLIENT_ID, START_CONTRACT_DATE, END_CONTRACT_DATE
The objective is to know the minimum date that a client is active regardless of the active contract, but it has to be from subsequente contracts.

I'll try to give examples to best clear this issue, cause it's difficult to explain by words.

**Example 1:**

| CLIENT_ID | CONTRACT_ID | START_CONTRACT_DATE | END_CONTRACT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 01/01/2012 | 05/04/2015 |
| 2 | 6 | 05/04/2015 | 13/06/2017 |
| 2 | 7 | 13/06/2017 | 22/05/2019 |
| 2 | 8 | 22/05/2019 | 31/12/9999 |

**Result:  01/01/2012**

**Example 2:**

| CLIENT_ID | CONTRACT_ID | START_CONTRACT_DATE | END_CONTRACT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2012 | 05/04/2015 |
| 1 | 2 | 02/09/2015 | 14/01/2017 |
| 1 | 3 | 13/06/2014 | 31/12/9999 |
| 1 | 4 | 25/03/2019 | 06/08/2020 |

**Result:  13/06/2014**

**Example 3:**

| CLIENT_ID | CONTRACT_ID | START_CONTRACT_DATE | END_CONTRACT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 01/01/2012 | 05/04/2015 |
| 3 | 6 | 05/04/2015 | 13/06/2017 |
| 3 | 7 | 13/06/2017 | 22/05/2018 |
| 3 | 8 | 22/05/2019 | 31/12/9999 |

**Result:  22/05/2019**

NOTE: I'm doing this on SAS Entreprise Guide, so the language I'm using is procsql, however, having the solution in any language would be useful!

Comment: In first example there should be 22/05/2019 as a result, shouldn't it? Other way I can't understand the 'algorithm' behind this.

Comment: Hello Marek! Its like that yeah. Basically I can translate the necessity to the minimum date in which the client has a contract without interrupting until the present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was written for T-SQL, but should show you what to do, assuming procsql has support for recursive ctes (unfortunately I have no experience with procsql):

```
declare @test table(client_id int, contract_id int, start_contract_date date, end_contract_date date)
INSERT INTO @test VALUES
(2, 5,  '2012-01-01',   '2015-04-05'),
(2, 6,  '2015-04-05',   '2017-06-13'),
(2, 7,  '2017-06-13',   '2019-05-22'),
(2, 8,  '2019-05-22',   '9999-12-31'),
(1, 1,  '2012-01-01',   '2015-04-05'),
(1, 2,  '2015-09-02',   '2017-01-14'),
(1, 3,  '2014-06-13',   '9999-12-31'),
(1, 4,  '2019-03-19',   '2020-08-06'),
(3, 5,  '2012-01-01',   '2015-04-05'),
(3, 6,  '2015-04-05',   '2017-06-13'),
(3, 7,  '2017-06-13',   '2018-05-22'),
(3, 8,  '2019-05-22',   '9999-12-31');

WITH CTE AS (SELECT MIN(
start_contract_date) AS start_contract_date, client_id
FROM @test 
WHERE end_contract_date > GETDATE()
GROUP BY client_id
UNION ALL 
SELECT t.start_contract_Date, t.client_id 
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN @test t ON c.start_contract_date = t.end_contract_date
AND c.client_id = t.client_id
)
SELECT MIN(start_contract_date), client_id 
FROM cte GROUP BY client_id;
```

Results:

| start_contract_date | client_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-06-13 | 1 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2 |
| 2019-05-22 | 3 |

If you are unaware of the mechanics of a recursive cte, there is an initial query, which simply takes the earliest start date for a current contract (where end date is after today). The second half (following the `Union all`) takes these initial results and then looks to go further back by pairing start dates with previous end dates, for the same client. If this succeeds, it tries again based on the new start date and so on until it finds no further matches. From the resultant values, we then take the earliest start date for each client.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! Could you explain the tought behind the process? It might help me convert to procsql :)

Comment: Please see my edit. If you have more questions,  feel free to come back.

Comment: Hello again Jonathan! I've never came across with that term, despite doing similar things! I'll try to search how to implement it on procsql, but you were a great help! 

Thank you so much!

Comment: I have checked.  Procsql does support recursive ctes in much the same way

Comment: You are a legend my friend! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using this you will have the minimum contract start date for every customer.
 `SELECT CLIENT_ID, MIN(START_CONTRACT_DATE) from tbl group by CLIENT_ID`

But if you want the biggest period, you can do something like this

`SELECT CLIENT_ID, MAX( DATEDIFF ( DAY, START_CONTRACT_DATE, END_CONTRACT_DATE) ) from tbl group by CLIENT_ID`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer! Its neither the Minimum nor the biggest period, its more complex. Basically it can translate the necessity to the minimum date in which the client has a contract without interrupting until the present.